# Generating an integer hash-code for any PHP value

Tags: php, hash, hashcode

I am looking for a way, in PHP, to generate an integer hash-code for any value - primitive types or user-defined classes (for a trie-like structure). This hash should have the following properties:

1. For objects `$x` and `$y` where `$x === $y`, `hashCode($x) === hashCode($y)`
2. Return a 32-bit value
3. Ideally, the hash function would be well distributed (i.e. not too many collisions)
4. As fast as possible (without writing a C extension)

The best I can come up with is to get a string hash and convert that to an integer:

```
<?php

function hashCode($o) {
    // Get a string hash for the value
    if( is_object($o) ) {
        // For objects, use spl_object_hash
        $strHash = spl_object_hash($o);
    }
    else {
        // Now we know we have a primitive type

        // For arrays, first hash the contents
        if( is_array($o) )
            $o = array_map(function($x) { return hashCode($x); }, $o);

        // Use serialisation to get a string for the primitive
        // NOTE: We could use casting to a string since, however this will
        //       lead to more collisions since, for instance,
        //       (string)true === '1'
        //       Also, casting a float to a string causes it to lose precision,
        //       meaning more collisions
        //       Maybe this is OK though...
        // We use md5 to reduce the size (think serialising a large string)
        $strHash = md5(serialize($o));
    }

    // Convert the string hash to a 32-bit integer
    return crc32($strHash);
}
```

Just wondered if anyone had any other ideas? To me, the array hashing seems particularly complicated and potentially slow. Also, I can't help thinking that I'm missing a method to go straight to an integer, or an alternative to `serialize`/`md5`/`crc32`...

Comment: What is the use-case, if you do not mind me asking?

Comment: There may be a conflict in how you are handling objects compared to arrays.  Object hashes are created from the unique object id for the runtime.  Creating one for an array would have to be derived from its value.  In other words, 2 identical arrays would have the same hash, while 2 clones of an object would not.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen - I am trying to implement a hash-array-mapped-trie for immutable maps (more out of curiosity than for anything useful, but it would be good if it could be useful...!)

Comment: @Flosculus - I am aware of that, and that is the intended behaviour. Two clones of an object would also fail a `===` test, so I am happy that their hashes would differ

Answer (score 0):

This is all the hashing options I could find.

Works for string, but can be converted to arrays / objects as well.

```
/**
 * Make a control key with the string containing datas
 *
 * @param  string $data        Data
 * @param  string $controlType Type of control 'md5', 'crc32' or 'strlen'
 * @throws Zend_Cache_Exception
 * @return string Control key
 */
protected function _hash($data, $controlType)
{
    switch ($controlType) {
    case 'md5':
        return md5($data);
    case 'crc32':
        return crc32($data);
    case 'strlen':
        return strlen($data);
    case 'adler32':
        return hash('adler32', $data);
    default:
        Zend_Cache::throwException("Incorrect hash function : $controlType");
    }
}
```